# Fast copy array & effective coding

Tags: delphi

what is the shortest ( nr. LoC)  & fastest ( Performance)  method to copy arrays with this array definition

```
Type  TPointSet = Array [1 .. 300] of TPoint;


 var  set1, set2 :  TPointSet;


 set2 := set1; //  not working , no compiler error
```

I don't want to loop my array and copy each item , any better option?

Comment: `set2 := set1` *DOES* work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Andreas says,

```
set2 := set1;
```

*does* work (if defined as in your question). What makes you think it doesn't?

What it needs to work is that both set1 and set2 *must* be defined as the same type *identifier*, not only as the same *type*.

This means that

```
 var  set1 : Array [1 .. 300] of TPoint;
      set2 : Array [1 .. 300] of TPoint;

 set2 := set1; //  not working , compiler error
```

*will* fail, as they are of the same *type* but not of the same type *identifier*. The difference here is between *type* (which can be multiple words/tokens) and *identifier* (which is always a single word/token).

(There are some cases that works despite not being typed as identical *identifier*, but for the most part, if you want to make a type assignment compatible between different variables of that type, you should define a specific type *identifier* for that type and use it on all variables that you need to be able to be assignment compatible with each other).

Comment: found issue on unexpected part of my code , thanks  for comments